# Accumulation of evidence in basic statistics

Tags: binomial-distribution, independence, joint-distribution

Imagine I have a coin, and I want to study tossing outcomes of that coin. I do this over two experiments. In the first experiment, I toss the coin $n_1$ times and write down all the outcomes, in the second I toss the coin $n_2$ times. Let's call the total data acquired in first and second experiment as $D_1$ and $D_2$ respectively. I'd say that the experiments do not appear to depend on each other, thus the probabilities of observing the data should be independent. I believe this can be written as follows

\begin{equation}P[D_1 \cup D_2] = P[D_1]P[D_2]\end{equation}

To the best of my understanding, the total data acquired $D = D_1 \cup D_2$ is independent of whatever I decide to call experiment one and experiment two. I could for example write down all of $n=n_1 + n_2$ outcomes (heads vs tails) in a line, color the first $n_1$ outcomes red and the remaining $n_2$ blue. Changing which outcomes are colored red and which blue will not change the values or the sequence of the outcomes. Thus, I should be able to write an explicit expression for the probability $P[D]$ which does not reference experiments one and two in any way, but only makes use of the data as a whole.

My goal is to write the explicit formulae for $P[D]$, $P[D_1]$ and $P[D_2]$ and show that the above equality holds. So far I have been unsuccessful in doing so. I have attempted to describe the data by only considering the number of heads and tails in each experiment, thus resulting in three binomial probability distributions. However, it is easy to verify the above equality does not hold if the data is described solely by the number of heads and tails. Namely, to the best of my understanding

$$
\begin{pmatrix}n \\ h\end{pmatrix}p^h(1-p)^t \neq
\begin{pmatrix}n_1 \\ h_1\end{pmatrix}p^{h_1}(1-p)^{t_1} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}n_2 \\ h_2\end{pmatrix}p^{h_2}(1-p)^{t_2}
$$

where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are the number of heads observed in each experiment, $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the number of tails, such that $h = h_1 + h_2$, $t = t_1 + t_2$, $t_1 = n_1 - h_1$, $t_2 = n_2 - h_2$.

**Question**: This is where I am stuck. I have two competing hypotheses on what is going on:

1. The equation does not hold because the number of heads does not completely describe the observed data $D$. Thus, the equation would hold if it involves complete information about the acquired data. If this is the case, I would kindly ask the responder to provide this complete description, and thus prove that the resulting equation holds.
2. My logic is flawed and the equation does not actually hold even using complete descriptions of data. If this is the case, I would appreciate being pointed to where exactly my argument breaks down.

Comment: The lack of clarity concerning how to summarize your experiment is what ultimately gives rise to this problem.  If you were to record *the entire sequence* of $n_1+n_2$ outcomes there would be no difficulty at all, because for such a sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n_1+n_2}$ (with $x_i\in\{0,1\}$) the likelihood would be $$\Pr(D)=\prod_{i=1}^{n_1+n_2}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}=\prod_{i=1}^{n_1}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}\prod_{i=n_1+1}^{n_1+n_2}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}=\Pr(D_1)\Pr(D_2).$$

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot. After so many years, I still misuse the binomial coefficient, mixing up the formula for data and for the sum.

Comment: May I ask another question. The question outlined here is a bit of a simplification. In my actual problem, I am working with two Poisson processes. So I had attempted to establish the above equation for the two Poisson distributions and failed. My best guess is that I have to transition into inter-event intervals, because the probabilities for those factor nicely for all events except the first. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Why not ask that specific question here instead?  Comments don't allow enough space to provide the details.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks again